# What high-level languages can I use to employ GPU computations acceleration?

Tags: java, scala, erlang, cuda, gpu

I think I am interested in using today GPUs powers (CUDA etc.) to accelerate my scientific number-crunching applications. But I am not willing to invest time in coding C/C++. I prefer Scala, but won't mind using Erlang, Haskell, F#, C#, Java, Python maybe, or an other language of this level. Is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[ScalaCL](http://code.google.com/p/scalacl/) is the main one for Scala.  It works through a set of specialised collections that'll defer work to the GPU via OpenCL.

Then there's also the [ScalaCL Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/scalacl/wiki/ScalaCLPlugin/), part of ScalaCL.  Which is a compiler plugin that'll automatically rewrite some of your code to use OpenCL bindings for acceleration, no extra work required!

Comment: Also ppl.stanford.edu has some  Scala gpu things,but nothing is released yet

Answer (score 4):

And don't forget [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html), [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/cuda-and-opencl-support/) and [Fortran](http://www.pgroup.com/resources/cudafortran.htm), all of which have CUDA support.  Mathematica supports OpenCL too.

Answer (score 3):

Java and Python have bindings for OpenCL.

You will have to write the GPU code in CUDA or OpenCL. Unless you found a library that did basic parallelization of loops.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Language_bindings lists bindings for Java (usable from Scala, but will need an adapting layer to make them more usable), .NET and Python.

See also https://github.com/ztellman/penumbra (Clojure) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/satnam_singh/archive/2009/12/15/gpgpu-and-x64-multicore-programming-with-accelerator-from-f.aspx and http://tomasp.net/blog/accelerator-intro.aspx (F#)